# Segmentation Fault C++ pointers

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ programming but I know that pointers cause segmentation error. The problem is in the Readline() method when I am trying to read a sudoku but I cannot fix it. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Sudoku.h"

using namespace std;

// Constructor
Sudoku::Sudoku(){
root=cells;
row=0;
row_ptr=&row;
}

void Sudoku::Readline(string s,int i) {
int lead;
for(int k=0;k<9;k++){
lead=(9*i)+k;
if (s[k]!=',') {
*(root+lead)=s[k];
} else {
*(root+lead)=0;
}
}
}

void Sudoku::MakeSudoku(string s){
//cout<<(*row_ptr)++<<' '<<s<<"\n";
Readline(s,(*row_ptr)++);
}
```

The class definition is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class Sudoku{
public:
int cells[81];
int row;
int *root;
int *row_ptr;
public:
Sudoku();
void MakeSudoku(string s);
void Readline(string s,int i);
void PrintSudoku();
};
```

The main file is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Sudoku.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
Sudoku sd;
// Input csv file containing sudoku
ifstream filen("sudoku.csv");
string s;
if(!filen.is_open()){
cout << "Error opening file";
} else{
    while(!filen.eof()){
    getline(filen,s);
    sd.MakeSudoku(s);
    } 
    }
filen.close();
//sd.PrintSudoku();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger and find the line where the fault happens.

Comment: The error is in Readline() method. I get no error when I remove the statements having *(root+lead). Infact, it compiles, but the output it gives is Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is no C++ code. Except file operations it is (bad styled) C code. You are using a plain array (cells), you even do an unnecessary copies of the array (root) and that pointer arithemtic is dangerous (as you are currently experiencing).

I think you should rewrite your code a bit which will solve your problem:

1. You should use descriptive variable names... k,s,i,etc. are hard to read
2. Use a two-dimensional array for 'cells'. Or even better a C++ container like a vector of vectors. The latter would check boundaries and you could get rid of your pointer arithmetics (which causes such faults when done the wrong way) and you could use plain indexes.
3. Use proper indentions and empty lines for block separation
4. Don't use magic numbers like "81" and "9". Create constants. Give them names! make them dependent from each other if they are dependent.